# How do i implement following layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to implement maps in a pop up window like this

[image]

So far i've done following :

1. Create a main activity with a button.
2. On click of the button, i lauch another activity which is subclass of MapsActivity.
3. Since maps can be created only in MapActivity, i applied Android Dialog theme to make
   the activity appear like a dialog.

   But still i'm not able to position the activity correctly under the button. Also, how can i have a callout like structure?

Answer (score 1):

use RelativeView. It will allow you to define size and make the position relative to right and upper border. you can also add paddings for the space in between.